# Route path for tags in two tables using acts_as_taggable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using acts_as_taggable gem to add tags to two separate models Articles and Coffeeshops. I have the ability to submit and display the tags in the two models separately perfectly fine. When you click the tag it also shows you a list of articles containing just that tag which is great. What I can't work out is how to do this for the Coffeeshops.  The path just takes you to the Articles index. I am certain I will need to change something in `routes.rb` and also the individual path in `coffeeshop/index.html.erb`

In routes I have :

`get 'tags/:tag', to: 'articles#index', as: :tag`

replicating this for coffeeshops obviously doesn't work. I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
 get 'tags/:article_tag, to 'articles#index, as: article_tag
 get 'tags/:coffeeshop_tag, to 'coffeeshops#index, as: coffeeshop_tag

get 'articles/tags/:article_tag, to 'articles#index, as: article_tag
get 'coffeeshops/tags/:coffeeshop_tag, to 'coffeeshops#index, as: coffeeshop_tag
```

Doesn't work either

But how do I change this in the view? I currently have:
`<%= raw(@article.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ')) %>`

I changed this to:

`<%= raw(@article.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, @article.tag_path(t) }.join(', ')) %>` but that only threw `undefined method 'tag_path' for #<Article:0x007fd49ab18f98>
Did you mean?  image_path` error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.

Updated view tags to:

`<%= raw(@coffeeshop.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, coffeeshops_tag_path(t) }.join(', ')) %>`.

And altered the route as below:

`get 'coffeeshops/tags/:tag', to: 'coffeeshops#index', as: :coffeeshops_tag`